# how can I send vCard through sms message in code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios4

how can I send vCards through sms message in code ? I want to build the vCard in code and send it in MFMessageComposeViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VCard sms isn't a normal SMS, so there is no way to do this is in the current SDK.